# How to lock DIV in LI tag from resize?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I want to create a responsive or re-sizable background pattern which has six colored strips. I have tried using `li` with multiple colors, but my problem is I couldn't lock my `li` when window is being re-sized. That is, the strips are not filling up the entire window size. How can I achieve this?

My code is provided below in the form of a snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.topper {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 40px 1px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 1366px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
li > div {
  height: 900px;
  width: 214px;
  display: block;
}
.g {
  background-color: #4885ed;
}
.go {
  background-color: #db3236;
}
.goo {
  background-color: #f4c20d;
}
.goog {
  background-color: #4885ed;
}
.googl {
  background-color: #3cba54;
}
.google {
  background-color: #db3236;
}
```

```html
<div class="topper">
</div>
<div class="bg">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="g"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="go"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="goo"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="goog"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="googl"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="google"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiiikooo/tk6z8gfa/)

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't lock" and why are you using multiple `li` for this background? It can be done with just one element.

Comment: YOU CAN'T use DIV inside LI!

Comment: @Harry I want my LI follow the window size

Comment: @jiff I'm sorry about that, do you have another solution with my multiple colors for background?

Comment: @kiki.kiko: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tk6z8gfa/1/) what you need?

Comment: @Harry yes I want to create multiple colors background vertically

Comment: @kiki.kiko I agree with harry's solution, it's exactly what you want and resizeable! (responsive)

Comment: @Harry thanks a lot :D

Comment: @jiff thanks a lot too, yes I want resizable background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with just one single element by using a `linear-gradient` as background instead of using multiple `li` elements. Also as jiff had pointed out, you shouldn't use `div` elements inside `li`.

By setting the element's size as equal to the screen size and by using percentage values for color-stops, the required effect can be achieved.

The gradient is created using the following logic:

- Six colored strips is required as background and so each colored strip can take only one-sixth of the element's background. That is, (100% / 6) which comes to around 16.66%.
- First color should start at 0% and end at 16.66% (color-stop) and so it should be written as below:

  ```
  <color> 0%, <color> 16.66%
  ```

  (*In the snippet, the `<color> 0%` is not written because it is assumed that first color starts at 0%*)
- Second color should start where the first element ended and should take up a further 16.66%. So it should start at 16.66% and end at 33.33%. This is why it is written as `#db3236 16.66%, #db3236 33.33%`.
- Similarly the third color starts where the second ended and takes another 16.66%. So its start is at 33.33% and end is at 49.99%. In the same way, start and end points for each color should get determined and then set in the `linear-gradient`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.topper {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 40px 1px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4885ed 16.66%, #db3236 16.66%, #db3236 33.33%, #f4c20d 33.33%, #f4c20d 49.99%, #4885ed 49.99%, #4885ed 66.66%, #3cba54 66.66%, #3cba54 83.33%, #db3236 83.33%, #db3236 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="topper">
</div>

<div class="bg">
</div>
```

Comment: how to count percentage in linear-gradient(to right, #4885ed 16.66%, #db3236 16.66%, #db3236 33.33%, #f4c20d 33.33%, #f4c20d 49.99%, #4885ed 49.99%, #4885ed 66.66%, #3cba54 66.66%, #3cba54 83.33%, #db3236 83.33%, #db3236 100%); ?

Comment: @kiki.kiko: I have added more details into the answer. Check and let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: oooh I see now 100%/6 = 16.66666666666667, thanks a lot for your kindness